# Git file statuses of files

Tags: git

According to the official git web site: [image: File states]

There are 4 states of files for git.
So the question is: what status have deleted and moved/renamed files?
Of course if the file is left in file system then after commit it will be untracked but before commit it has deleted status (for deletion). I think deletion is not really a file modification but an event.

Comment: Does the documentation surrounding this image suggest that these are the only statuses for a file? The documentation on `git status` perhaps indicates that there are others: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format ' ' = unmodified

M = modified

A = added

D = deleted

R = renamed

C = copied

U = updated but unmerged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a delete or a rename exactly like an edit in this diagram.  It doesn't matter if you're making a content change (editing the file), making a metadata change (setting the file executable, for example) or deleting it, it goes through the same workflow.

If you have a file committed to git (in the teal "unmodified" state in your diagram) and you delete it, you are now in the "modified" state.  git has detected this change:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    foo.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

At this point the file is removed on-disk but not staged for deletion.  It's in the yellow "modified" state.  To stage it, you can stage it just like any other change, by running `git add foo.txt`.

Recall, despite the name, `git add` doesn't *add* a file, it *stages the change to a file*.  In this case, the change is a delete, so `git add` will stage a delete.

(I mention this only to prove a point, in fact, it's much more natural to run `git rm` to stage a file's removal.  Either will work.)

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    foo.txt
```

At this point, the file is in the red "staged" state.  When you commit this change, the file will no longer exist in the repository.

```
[master 3b58d71] deleted
 1 file changed, 7 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 foo.txt
```

Recreating the file will start over in the grey "untracked" state.

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    foo.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer